# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property '0' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yeah, i know its one of famous possible duplicate question. but i dont find how to sort it out in my code.

```
let newVlaue = [];
$(".displayInlineBlock").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find("input").is(':checked') && !$(this).find("label").hasClass("allselect")) {
    if ($(this).find("input").attr('id')) {
      let chosenValue = $(this).find("input").attr('id');
      let tempValue = chosenValue.match(/\d+/g);
      tempValue = parseInt(tempValue[0]);
      if (tempValue == 0) {
        newVlaue.push(tempValue);
      } else {
        newVlaue.push(tempValue - 1);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks for your kind help

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: where does the error takes place?

Comment: @NinaScholz, I suppose here : `tempValue[0]`.

Comment: `tempValue` would be a number or `NaN`.

Comment: @NinaScholz, no,`tempValue` would be an array:  `let tempValue = chosenValue.match(/\d+/g);`.

Comment: @Nina Scholz . tnx for jumping into this. 

am checking number or NAN as nina said

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut tnx for response am checking now

Comment: @NinaScholz, yes, would be a number after apply `parseInt` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a check if the result of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is `null` or not. If not, proceed.

```
let tempValue = chosenValue.match(/\d+/g); // result is null if no numbers are found
if (tempValue !== null) {
    // proceed
}
```

If not matches values should included with zero, you could add a default array with zero.

```
let tempValue = chosenValue.match(/\d+/g) || [0];
```

Comment: can u tell me how to push multiple selected checkbox using javascript

Comment: maybe you ask another question with this purpose, because answering addition parts without highlighting the problem with a detailed view is not the right place here in comments.